# BitBucket SSH Cloning Git

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, clone

Following BitBucket docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html

This is the example code snippet of cloning using git. But when using the **":"** I get an error of "could not resolve hostname" but when I use **"/"** I don't have any issues. What am I missing? Is the documentation incorrect?

---

```
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different syntaxes for git SSH URLs:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git
```

and

```
git@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a

The Bitbucket docs mixed these two. This is an error in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that every Bitbucket repo has a "Clone" button at the top right of the repo's home page. You can copy the correct `git clone` command from there.