# "Error parsing URL" when cloning repository using GIT LFS

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I am trying to clone a GIT repository from Bitbucket which apparently uses GIT LFS:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name/
```

While cloning the repository partially works, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing URL "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name.git/info/lfs": parse git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name.git/info/lfs: first path segment in URL cannot contain colonError parsing URL "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name.git/info/lfs": parse git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name.git/info/lfs: first path segment in URL cannot contain colonFiltering contenFiltering content: 100% (3/3), 49.97 MiB | 6.59 MiB/s, done.
```

GIT LFS is installed:

```
$ git-lfs.exe --version
git-lfs/2.9.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git 8ab05aa7)
```

I am using GIT 2.24.0 on Windows:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.24.0.windows.2
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can I ignore this? How can I fix this error? Is this even a GIT LFS error (or some custom script failing that I don't know about)?

Comment: shouldn't you have forward slash "/" instead of ":" in URL after git@bitbucket.org?git@bitbucket.org:companyname/repository-name/

Comment: I don't know. Would that work? What I do know is that using a colon works for me in all other repositories when cloning them via SSH.

Comment: yes, that's by design. should have ssh or http and / inplace of URL.

Comment: Nope, forward slash does not work at all. I tried `$ git clone git@bitbucket.org/companyname/repository-name/` and got `fatal: repository 'git@bitbucket.org/companyname/repository-name/' does not exist`.

Comment: What is the correct URL format when using SSH?

Comment: It looks like this works: `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy/`. Feel free to answer it to get the reputation. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: something like - ssh://git@git.<organisation>/<project>/<repo>.git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036062/7976758

Comment: That's a different issue. They used an invalid syntax (starting with `ssh://` and using a colon). The colon syntax is valid without the `ssh://` and works, but it does not work with GIT LFS, which is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL pattern should start with either "ssh/http" and should have "/" instead of ":" as -

```
ssh://git@git.<organisation>/<project>/<repo>.git
```